# Unable to call a SOAP API wsdl method programmatically

Tags: node.js, soapui

[Screenshot of first part of request through soap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q82OD.jpg)
I need to call a method defined in the wsdl. I am able to do this using SOAP UI. I get the following response as seen in screenshot:
[Screenshot of 2nd part of request through soap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5k0s.jpg)

I then tried accessing the same method using the same parameters as via the SoapUP module, using the following javascript code

```
soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
//console.log(client)
  client.<<wsdlFunctionName>>(args, function(err, result) {
      console.log(result);
  });
});
```

I got the following error 
"Unhandled rejection Error: a:InternalServiceFault: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Don't see the referenced screenshot.

Comment: can you see the screenshots now ?

Comment: Yes, the links show. I changed second image location in the post as indicated by the narrative. Most readers don't appreciate having to open multiple links. Whenever possible post actual text.

Comment: Or embed images in the question narrative. But if the info is textual, the actual text is preferable.

Comment: okay I'll post it

Comment: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:bur="http://URL">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:methodName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:Obj_methodName>
            <!--Optional:-->
           
            <bur:XMLRequest></bur:XMLRequest>
         </tem:Obj_methodName>
      </tem:methodName>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>